# Delete elements from one-to-many relationships when removing them from a JPA Entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA (Hibernate) with the following entity class with one one-to-many relationship.

When I add elements to the list, and then persist the Organization entity, it adds the new elements to the proyects table, but when I remove elements from the list, nothing happens when persist (or merge), and I would like these elements to be removed from the database.

I tried also *orphanRemoval=true* in the OneToMany annotation, but it doesn't work.

```
@Entity
public class Organization {     

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public long internalId;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "organization")
    private List<Proyect> proyects;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `Proyect.organization` to null and update that entity, since this property is responsible for the database entry (`Proyect` is the owning side in this case ).

Comment: This doesn't work, in the database the Proyect table is updated with foreign key equal to null

Comment: @greuze setting the foreign key to null is what you want when removing a project from the organisation, don't you? If you don't remove the foreign key, the project is still part of the organisation.

Comment: The proyects are only part from Organization (one proyect cannot be in two organizations), so I want that when I remove a proyect from the proyect list in Organization, it is removed from the database too

Comment: @greuze I see. Try and add the Hibernate annotation `@Cascade( CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)` to your list definition.

Comment: Did you find sollution?